# Directly Instansiating a DSP Slice Without IP Core

Tags: vhdl, xilinx, vivado

### The Problem

I want:

`p <= (d-a) * b`

Trying to directly instantiate a DSP block by using a DSP48E1 instead of simply writing `p <= (d-a) * b` plus it helps me understand how this block works for the future. So far I've had little luck with it though.

Referencing this article:

http://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/user_guides/ug479_7Series_DSP48E1.pdf

### Attempt

These are my current settings:

```
a <= std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(5, 30));
b <= std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(1, 18));
d <= std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(20, 25));

    dsp : DSP48E1
    generic map (
        USE_DPORT => True,
        ALUMODEREG => 0, 
        CARRYINREG => 0,
        CARRYINSELREG => 0,
        CREG => 0
        )
    port map(
        clk => clk,
        acin => std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(1, 30)), -- cascaded data input
        alumode => "0000", -- control bits to select logic unit inputs
        bcin => std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(1, 18)), -- cascaded data input 
        carrycascin => '0', -- cascaded data input
        carryin => '0',  -- carry input
        carryinsel => "000", -- selects carry source
        cea1 => '1', -- clock enable if AREG = 2 or INMODE0 = 1
        cea2 => '1', -- clock enable if AREG = 1 or 2
        cead => '1', -- clock enable for AD pipeline register
        cealumode => '0', -- clock enable for ALUMODE --0
        ceb1 => '1', -- clock enable if BREG = 1 or INMODE4 = 1
        ceb2 => '1', -- clock enable if BREG = 1 or 2
        cec => '0', -- clock enable for C
        cecarryin => '0', -- clock enable
        cectrl => '0', -- clock enable for OPMODE and CARRYINSEL ctrl registers
        ced => '1', -- clock enable for D
        ceinmode => '0',-- **** clock enable input registers
        cem => '0', -- clock enable for the post multiply M register and the internal multiply round CARRYIN register
        cep => '1', -- clock enable 
        inmode => "01101", -- *selects functionality of preadder [3] = sign, [4] = B multiplier sel
        multsignin => '0', -- MACC extension sign
        opmode =>  "0000101", -- *** Control input to A, Y and Z multiplexers
        pcin => std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(1, 48)), -- cascade input
        rsta => rst,
        rstallcarryin => '0',
        rstalumode => '0',
        rstb => rst,
        rstc => '0',
        rstctrl => rst,
        rstd => rst,
        rstinmode => rst,
        rstm => rst,
        rstp => rst,
        a => a,--_dsp, -- bits 29:25 used in second stage preadder 
        b => b,--_dsp,
        c => c_dsp,
        d => d,--_dsp,
        p => p_dsp
    );
```

I always get `p = 0` even if I force `d = 20, a = 5, b = 1`.

I figured I should keep `ALUMODE` and `OPMODE` at `0` since I'm skipping the final stage and just want a straight subtraction and multiplication.

### Photos

[image: DSP]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at table 2-7 from the [DSP48E1 user guide](http://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/user_guides/ug479_7Series_DSP48E1.pdf) page 34.

Your current configuration performs, at the post-adder, `P = Z + X + Y + CIN`, with `Z = 0`, `X = 0` and `Y = 0`. You see the problem here?

The `OPMODE` signals control the value of the multiplexers. You want `OPMODE(6 downto 4) = "000"`, so that `Z` keeps its null value. However, you want `OPMODE(3 downto 0) = "0101"` to set `X/Y` to the multiplier output `M`. `ALUMODE` should keep it's current value, it's fine.

Comment: I added a picture in my question above to help understand.

So the Z part is obviously 0 as we block off the C signal here. Though when you switch X and Y on, I sort of get it as it says in the documentation:

`Y: "01", X: "01", Multiplexer Output: M` - so this is just a rule for OPMode when outputting a multiplication - but why do both have to be switched on? Or does one output the MSBs and the other LSBs?

Comment: And it's still outputting 0... grrr

Comment: I'm not quite sure why it need X and Y to be M. My best guess would be that the multiplier does not output a valid multiplication result, but rather 2 partial products whose sums is the multiplication. It makes sense to force the use of the output adder and yield a better pipeline/timings results.

Comment: So there's nothing else you can see in there which would result in outputting of 0?

Comment: As to why it's not working, I'm not so sure... I suggest you make a simple design in VHDL, synthesize it and look at the schematic to figure out how it configured the DSP48 and what you did wrong...

Comment: Default generics use registers for OPMODE and ALUMODE, and I just saw your `cectrl` and `cealumode` are both `'0'`, keeping both at 0. Either set those to `'1'` or remove the pipline registers (generics ALUMODEREG and OPMODEREG).

Comment: Except OPMODE is used now ;)

Comment: You disable the multiplier register! Either set the signal `CEM` to `'1'` or disable it entirely by setting the generic `MREG`  to 0.

Comment: I told you earlier to set `cectrl` to `'1'` or to use the generics `ALUMODEREG` and `OPMODEREG` to disable the pipeline. You decided to keep `cectrl` to `0` and didn't disable the pipeline register on `opmode`. Set ` cectrl`to `1` or add the ` OPMODEREG` generic.